# How to add a dynamic calculation as a criteria?

Tags: excel, range, criteria, formula, countif

Let's say that in column A, I have a list of starting dates and in column B, I have a list of ending dates. I wish to build one formula (without adding an extra column) that counts how many time the ending date exceeds 120 days from the starting date.

I tried the following formula in C1:

`=COUNTIF(B:B,A:A-120)`

but it's not working since the second attribute of the COUNTIF formula is a criteria, it doesn't seem to accept a range. It treats A:A as A1 because I put my formula in C1.

*Note: it needs to be solved with only one formula, can't add extra columns or arrays, and no VBA.*

*UPDATE: some of rows have "NULL" written when no dates are available and therefore it doesn't work with `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A<B:B-120))`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SUMPRODUCT` instead, where you can use ranges:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A<B:B-120))
```

If A:A is smaller than B:B after removing 120 days, then `(A:A<B:B-120)` will return true for each row where this applies, and false otherwise.

`--` at the start will convert those to 1s and 0s respectively and `SUMPRODUCT` add them.

Note that the formula will be faster if you use a smaller range, e.g. A1:A100 and B1:B100 (or whatever range you're counting).

---

Try using this if you have non-dates in your range as well:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(A:A<B:B-120,0)*1)
```

And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in the formula to array invoke it (you can use `SUMPRODUCT`, but it will require the array invocation so you might as well just use `SUM`) .

Comment: At first I didn't understand the `--`. Then I thought "why didn't he use `1*`" and it became clear.

Comment: @stenci It's the same as using `*1` or `+0` :) Thanks @pnuts!

Comment: It works well if there are dates on every row. However, some of the lines have no dates and show only NULL in both A and B. Therefore, it returns an error. Any way to fix that?

Comment: After further testing, `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A<B:B-120)*ISNUMBER(B:B)*ISNUMBER(A:A))` still doesn't the solve. Since we are applying a calculation (B:B-120), it returns an error. Any way to fix this? I tried `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A<N(B:B-120))*--(ISNUMBER(B:B))*--(ISNUMBER(A:A)))` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Faust Ok, I was thinking earlier that the error would be gone with this check. I tried a few things now and have edited my answer for a working formula.